# Exporting Outlook 2010 Calendar

Tags: calendar, microsoft-outlook-2010, export

I couldn't find any option to export my calendar in Outlook 2010 as a ical file. Is there such an option in Microsoft Outlook 2010?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

File -> Save Calendar. It saves the file as .ics which is the standard iCalendar file format used by the iCal app.

[image]

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICalendar

Before you Save, click on MORE OPTIONS to change the **Date Range** and **Details**. Otherwise the default Date Range is "Today". [image] [image]

Answer (score 3):

Note that "Save Calendar" will rename all your appointments to "Busy" or "Tentative" with no explanation.
A better way is to go to File -> Open -> Import
Choose "Export to file"
Export your calendar to a CSV file.  It will prompt you for a date range.
You can then go to your other calendar and Import the CSV file.
This at least works for Google Calendar.

I use the Google Calendar Sync for my home Outlook, and I was going to install it at work, but I suspect it puts everything into the same calendar so I didn't try it because I want my work appointments in a separate calendar from my personal appointments.

Comment: Odd that the export option is in the list under Export, but this works great.

Comment: That is not correct, you can set the detail level to "Full Details" to obtain the entire entries. Advanced even offers the option to only do so for entries not marked as private.